# org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException while connecting to Hive using Java JDBC

Tags: java, hive

My hiveserver2 is up & running. I'm trying to connect to hive using Java JDBC

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/sample", "", "");
```

I'm facing the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hduser is not allowed to impersonate anonymous
```

Comment: Please add/modify below properties in your core-site.xml           1) hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups=*
2)  hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts=*

Comment: core-site.xml present in hadoop/etc/hadoop ??

Comment: add two line given above to your core-site.xml